# In PostGIS, how to assign TIMESTAMPs to each POINT in a LINESTRING?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to use LINESTRING to record the path of car driving, which has both spatial information and time information.

In PostGIS, is there a way to assign timestamps to each POINT in a LINESTRING?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible because linestrings are stored in a binary format, the so-called [Enhanced Well-Known Binary (EWKB)](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT) format. In that format, you cannot associate any information with the individual co-ordinates.

What you can do is to store the points along the path of the car in (a) separate table(s) and then associate those points with linestrings - presumably a road network - using the standard PostGIS functions such as `ST_Distance()`, `ST_ClosestPoint()` or any of those for [linear referencing](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Linear_Referencing).

Your model would be something like this:

```
table: car
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY
  ...

table: ride
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY
  car  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES car
  ...

table: ride_path
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY
  ride integer NOT NULL REFERENCES ride
  loc  geometry(4326, 'POINT') NOT NULL
  tim  timestamp
  ...
```

With this structure you can use standard SQL queries to associate every location of a car to a specific linestring, or to some position along a linestring (e.g. `ST_LineLocatePoint()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been storing GPS tracks by using the LINESTRINGM format, storing the timestamps as "unix time_t" values (i.e, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00) in the M coordinate. It requires some conversions to get to and from a more SQL-friendly time format, but it keeps things neatly together.

Comment: In retrospect, it might be better to store the start time of the track as a separate column, and offsets from the start in the M values. This might save some headaches with time_t:s and leap seconds, for example.